# Not even Cuba a true island nation

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image: cryptic crossword]
>
> ACROSS
>
> 1. Country's initial trade union with endless value (6)
> 2. Arrangement before wordplay backfires (6)
> 3. Hiding in a Uruguayan Republic (5)
> 4. Pacific nation to place friend before treasure (5)
>
> DOWN
>
> 1. A face has a vase or a hot place (7)
> 2. Expose unnoted beef (4)
> 3. Initially, voters acknowledged not even Cuba a true island nation (7)
> 4. Rock formation left and right; German boots left, right and centre  (5)
> 5. Crawl up using secret condition (5)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**ACROSS**

1. Country's initial trade union with endless value (6)

   > Tuvalu  - **t**rade **u**nion + **valu**e
2. Arrangement before wordplay backfires (6)

   > Prenup - Pre + pun, reversed
3. Hiding in a Uruguayan Republic (5)

   > Nauru - i**n a Uru**guayan (thanks, Misha Lavrov for suggesting the interpretation).
4. Pacific nation to place friend before treasure (5)

   > Palau - Pal + Au (gold)

**DOWN**

1. A face has a vase or a hot place (7)

   > Furnace - F(urn)ace
2. Expose unnoted beef (4)

   > Veal - Reveal with out Re
3. Initially, voters acknowledged not even Cuba a true island nation (7)

   > Vanuatu - **v**oters **a**cknowledged **n**ot + C**u**b**a** a **t**r**u**e
4. Rock formation left and right; German boots left, right and centre (5)

   > Uluru - I think this might be U-*boats* (instead of boots?) where *u* is left, right and centre of the word and l (left) and r (right) are also included.
5. Crawl up using secret condition (5)

   > Lupus - Craw**l up us**ing

Crossword filled in

> [image]

Comment: 10 minutes? Just wow.

Comment: @jafe Thanks, I really like your cryptic puzzles, they are a lot of fun.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: Well done! I didn't see the last two. (And I didn't see what the [boots](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-Boot) were. Hm.)

Comment: @hexomino you are good with words! respect!

Comment: After reading the solution I still don't see the relation to the title of the question. Can you edit that in?

Comment: @Vincent I just thought it was playing off the clue in 3 down. I don't see a direct connection to the solution.

Comment: @Vincent I can see why you'd look for a connection, in some puzzles there's an extra layer related to the title somehow. Not the case here, though... I've changed the title so that it's not a question :)

Comment: My reading of 3 across was that jr gnxr gur svefg gjb yrggref bs anheh sebz gur jbeqf "va n" orsber "hehthnlna" - guvf znxrf vg n zber genqvgvbany "uvqvat" pyhr.

Comment: @MishaLavrov yes, that makes more sense actually, I'll change to that.